# How to know the time spent in a function with the tool kcachegrind

Tags: c, valgrind

I've recently starting using this tool and the file that it creates has 4 column, Inc., Self., Called and function.

The first two column seems to indicates the percentage of time spent in each function.

Despite looking into the documentation, I  can't find a way to determine how much time exactly is spent in each function. I could calculate it myself if I knew how much time the program takes to execute, but I don't find this information in the file produced by kcachegrind.

Does this tool provide somewhere this information, or do I have to use something like `clock_gettime`to  calculate it myself?

Answer (score 2):

That's not how cachegrind and callgrind work. By default, callgrind just counts instruction retirement (IRs). There are options to add simple cache and branch prediction models.

cachegrind does similar instruction counting, but with the cache simulation turned on by default. This is a useful and easy obtain measurement. The instruction count is very accurate, but it is not an exact indication of the time that it spent.

I don't think that it is possible at all these days to be able to say "machine instruction X takes N clock cycles and T nanoseconds". The Intel CPU databooks stopped including that sort of information I guess about 15 years ago.

If you want accurate time measurements then you need to instrument your code with a high resolution timer, run it on a machine with no other users/processors running. and even then you will need multiple runs and will likely get different results for the first result (cold cache) and subsequent runs (warn cache).

Lastly I recommend Brendan Gregg's books on performance measurement and BPF.